# "Flask-login" Cookie created but app not behaving as required?

Tags: python, flask-login

I am trying to get user to login and then redirect them to '/user' and maintain session using flask-login.

**Login function:**

```
@app.route('/login',methods=['GET','POST'])
def login():
    if(request.method == 'POST'):
            userid = request.form['email'].encode('utf-8')
            passwd = request.form['password'].encode('utf-8')
            user = User(userid,passwd)
            if user:
                login_user(user,force=True)
                return redirect(url_for('user'))

            else:
                return redirect(url_for('main'))

    else:
            return redirect(url_for('main'))
```

My user function has header of @login_required and the code is:

```
@app.route('/user', methods=['GET'])
@login_required
def user():
    if(request.method == 'GET'):
        userid = request.args.get('user.userid')
        return render_template('User.html',name = userid)
```

According to this user must be redirected to user function when authentication is done but it instead returns back to 'main' because of code given below:

```
@login_manager.unauthorized_handler
def unauthorized():
    return redirect(url_for('main'))
```

I checked my browser it has a cookie named 'session' and 'remember-token' which means user session is created successfully. 
Why is the app not redirecting to user?

Comment: Looks like `user = User(userid,passwd)` returns `None` for some reason. Are the user credentials valid? You can try logging the output or calling the constructor "by hand".

Comment: I think they are valid else session cookie would not have been created which is under if user and i checked for user instance and I my function recieved user instance

Comment: Can you confirm that the `if user:` block is indeed entered? It will really narrow down the search for your problem

Comment: In if user block i have tried a basic template with following code: {% if current_user.is_authentic  %}{% current_user %}{% endif %} and this template shows user instance. Does this verifies that it is going in if user block? I can try any other method if you'd like.

Comment: I tried this template in place of return redirect(url_for('user'))